# How to add a new application to phabricator?

Tags: php, phabricator

I'm currently working on a project where i need to add a new application to phabricator like a custom task board, but i can't seem to find any useful documentation.
can someone give me an idea on where to start or some link to useful docs.thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any current guide for building applications, however there are 50+ applications in Phabricator to serve as an example. Badges is a more modern example.